# How can I add a CSS class to the existing CSS class in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is there any way that I can add a new CSS class to the existing CSS class using jQuery?

For example, I have the following code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" cssClass="cl_ref_unit_address_1 mapUnit"/>
```

I want to add `m_sale` into the `cssClass` attribute without replacing the existing class (value). Desired output:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" cssClass="m_sale cl_ref_unit_address_1 mapUnit"/>
```

Comment: Is `<asp:TextBox ID="sUnit" runat="server" MaxLength="12" Width="3em" cssClass="cl_ref_unit_address_1 mapUnit"/>` `html` rendered at `document` ?
`

Comment: I assume that "cssClass" not an actual CSS class in HTML terms, so maybe something like `$('asp').attr('cssClass', 'm_sale ' + $('asp').attr('cssClass'));`

Comment: I don't know `asp` but is `cssClass` after processing _passed_ as `class` to the client?  If so whats wrong with [`jQuery.addClass`](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)?

Comment: `$('#sUnit').addClass('m_sale');` ???

Comment: @ Robbie Averill.. i think it will not work if it is rendering in client side

Answer (score 0):

you can try this .

```
$( "YourSeletorHere" ).addClass( "yourClass" );
```

for example

```
$( ".ClassName" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Or

```
$( "#ElementId" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how asp renders html, but if you can render a jquery script like below then it should be able to add class to desired html tag :

```
<script>        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('.cl_ref_unit_address_1').addClass('m_sale');
    });        
</script>
```